# In Kivy, changing the vertices of a mesh that is drawn to a FBO breaks the FBO when it is inside a ScreenManager

Tags: python, kivy, fbo

Below is minimal runnable example of what I believe to be a bug in kivy.

In this program, a scene is drawn to a FBO. The scene is then drawn with a glsl shader to apply a post-processing filter that makes everything grayscale.

When my post-processing widget is inside a ScreenManager, it only correctly draws the scene for a small number (3) of frames. It then draws nothing (BUG?). If it is not inside a ScreenManager, it runs perfectly.

I have narrowed down the bug to a single line of offending code, which is where I modify the vertices of a very simple mesh drawn in the scene. THe first couple of times I modify the mesh it works correctly, but more than that, the FBO is blank. Any ideas about why that might be the case?

Inside the code are many comments to guide the reader, and just after the imports are a couple of constants that can be used to switch between having the program run in a minimal screen manager (where there is a bug) or outside of it, where you can see the program working as it should.

I have tried to make the code as clear and minimal as possible. It's still a bit large. Please ask if you have questions!

```
from math import pi,cos,sin,atan2,ceil,sqrt
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.graphics.opengl import *
from kivy.graphics.shader import *
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.resources import resource_find
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics.transformation import Matrix

### You can configure this script here to demonstrate how the Widget
### hierarchy affects the bug, and how the number of times that the
### Sprite's mesh is updated influences the bug.

### One of the following two lines should be commented out.
WIDGET_SETUP = 'NO_SCREEN_MANAGER' ## NO BUG
#WIDGET_SETUP = 'INSIDE_SCREEN_MANAGER' ## BUG !!!

## I used the constant below to identify the number of frames
## correctly drawn, when in the INSIDE_SCREEN_MANAGER
## configuration. If the following constant is set above this critical
## threshold (>3 on my laptop), then the PostProcessor ceases to draw
## *anything*, including the Rectangles that are part of a separate
## RenderContext. If it is set low enough, then you see the first
## couple of frames drawn. And then the view stops being updated, but
## continues to be displayed correctly.

## A value of '-1' does not limit the number of frames updated.
NUMBER_OF_FRAMES_TO_UPDATE_MESH_VERTICES = -1


## CONFUSINGlY, decreasing the step size (amount of time between
## iterations) makes it so that even the first frame is not drawn.
## Why would this matter? It seems to me like something is happening
## at the end of the ScreenManagers transition to the screen??  This
## is just a wild guess..
DT = 0.2 ## DT = 0.01 makes not even the first frame be drawn.


class Sprite(object) :
    def __init__(self,postProcessor) :
        self.iteration = 0

        ## render context for applying a shader to the rendering of
        ## this sprite's mesh
        self.spriteRC = RenderContext(use_parent_projection=False)

        self.r = 0.1 # width of square to draw
        self.a = 0.0

        ## uniform values for shader
        self.spriteRC['modelview_mat'] = postProcessor.projectionMatrix
        self.spriteRC['window_size'] = [float(Window.width),float(Window.height)]
        self.spriteRC['color'] = [1.,1.,1.,1.]

        ## set up texture
        self.uvsize = 1.,1.
        self.uvpos = 0.,0.

        ## compile shader ## this shader gives the color according to
        ## the texture coordinates..
        self.spriteRC.shader.vs = """        
          /* Outputs to the fragment shader */
          varying vec2 tex_coord0;
          varying vec4 frag_color;

          /* vertex attributes */
          attribute vec2     vPosition;
          attribute vec2     vTexCoords0;

          /* uniform variables */
          uniform mat4       modelview_mat;
          uniform mat4       projection_mat;

          void main() {
          tex_coord0 = vTexCoords0;
          frag_color = vec4(0.,0.,0.,0.); // I don't understand why this line is necessary, but it is.
          gl_Position = projection_mat * modelview_mat * vec4(vPosition.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
        }"""

        self.spriteRC.shader.fs = """
        /* Outputs from the vertex shader */
        varying vec2 tex_coord0;        

        void main (void){
          gl_FragColor = vec4(tex_coord0.x,tex_coord0.y,tex_coord0.x,1.0);
        }"""

        if not self.spriteRC.shader.success :
            raise Exception('Effect shader compile failed.')

        ## set up mesh, and add it to the render context 
        self.mesh = Mesh(mode = 'triangles')
        self.mesh.indices=range(6)
        self.initializeVertices()
        self.iterate(0.0)
        self.spriteRC.add(self.mesh)    

        ## add this sprite's render context to the fbo in the postprocessor
        postProcessor.addSpriteRenderContext(self.spriteRC)

    def initializeVertices(self) :
        self.vs = [-self.r,-self.r, self.uvpos[0],               self.uvpos[1],
                   -self.r,+self.r, self.uvpos[0],               self.uvpos[1]+self.uvsize[1],
                   +self.r,-self.r, self.uvpos[0]+self.uvsize[0],self.uvpos[1],
                   +self.r,+self.r, self.uvpos[0]+self.uvsize[0],self.uvpos[1]+self.uvsize[1],
                   +self.r,-self.r, self.uvpos[0]+self.uvsize[0],self.uvpos[1],
                   -self.r,+self.r, self.uvpos[0],               self.uvpos[1]+self.uvsize[1],
              ]

    def updateVertices(self) :
        """ Changes those parts of the mesh that need to be changed """
        xr = cos(self.a)*self.r - sin(self.a)*self.r
        yr = sin(self.a)*self.r + cos(self.a)*self.r

        self.vs[0::4] = -xr,-yr,+yr,+xr,+yr,-yr
        self.vs[1::4] = -yr,+xr,-xr,+yr,-xr,+xr


    def iterate(self,dt) :
        self.iteration += 1
        self.a += 0.05 
        self.updateVertices()

        if (NUMBER_OF_FRAMES_TO_UPDATE_MESH_VERTICES < 0 or 
            self.iteration < NUMBER_OF_FRAMES_TO_UPDATE_MESH_VERTICES) : 
            ## the following line is what causes the post-processor's
            ## FBO to break, again only when 1. the post-processor is
            ## inside a ScreenManager, and after a certain number of
            ## frames have gone by (3-10 in my experience).
            self.mesh.vertices=self.vs


class PostProcessor(Widget) :
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        Logger.debug('world.init()')

        self.setupPostProcessorRenderContext()

        ## draw a colored rectangle on to the fbo. This is independent
        ## of the sprite RC and demonstrates that when the bug occurs,
        ## the FBO ceases to draw anything at all
        self.rectangleRC = RenderContext(use_parent_projection=False)
        self.rectangleRC['modelview_mat'] = self.projectionMatrix
        self.rectangleRC.add(Color(0,1,0,0.5))
        self.rectangleRC.add(Rectangle(pos=(0.0,0.0),size=(0.5,0.5))) 
        self.fbo.add(self.rectangleRC)      

        self.canvas = self.postProcessorRC
        super(PostProcessor, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def setupPostProcessorRenderContext(self) :
        """This RenderContext is responsible ONLY for drawing the FBO (and
        applying a postprocessing shader to it). Both the rectangleRC
        and spriteRC draw directly to the FBO.

        """
        self.postProcessorRC=RenderContext()
        self.postProcessorRC.shader.vs = """
        /* Outputs to the fragment shader */
        varying vec4 frag_color;
        varying vec2 tex_coord0;

        /* vertex attributes */
        attribute vec2     vPosition;
        attribute vec2     vTexCoords0;

        /* uniform variables */
        uniform mat4       modelview_mat;
        uniform mat4       projection_mat;
        uniform vec4       color;
        uniform float      opacity;

        void main (void) {
          frag_color = color * vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, opacity);
          tex_coord0 = vTexCoords0;
          gl_Position = projection_mat * modelview_mat * vec4(vPosition.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
        }"""

        self.postProcessorRC.shader.fs = """
        /* Outputs from the vertex shader */
        varying vec4 frag_color;
        varying vec2 tex_coord0;

        /* uniform texture samplers */
        uniform sampler2D texture0;

        uniform vec2 resolution;
        uniform float time;

        void main() {
          vec4 rgb = texture2D(texture0, tex_coord0);
          float c = (rgb.x + rgb.y + rgb.z) * 0.3333;
          gl_FragColor = vec4(c,c,c, 1.0);
        }"""

        if not self.postProcessorRC.shader.success :
            raise Exception('Effect shader compile failed.')

        with self.postProcessorRC:
            # create the fbo
            self.fbo = Fbo(size=(float(Window.width), float(Window.height)))

            # show our fbo on the PostProcessor Widget render context
            ## by drawing a rectangle covering most of screen, with
            ## the texture set to self.fbo
            Color(1, 1, 1)
            Rectangle(pos=(-0.9,-0.9),
                      size=(1.8,1.8),
                      texture=self.fbo.texture)

        ## the following linear algebra sets the screen up nicely, so
        ## that the largest window dimension (width or height) ranges
        ## between -1 and 1, and the smaller dimension ranges between
        ## smallerDimSize/largerDimSize. This makes a square e.g. 0,0;
        ## 0,1; 1,1; 1,0 render as a square (rather than a rectangle).
        self.projectionMatrix = Matrix()
        self.projectionMatrix.look_at(0.,0.,1.,  # eye position coords
                                      0.,0.,0.,  # looking at these coords
                                      0,1.,0)    # a vector that points up

        if Window.height > Window.width :
            self.xRadius = float(Window.width)/Window.height
            self.yRadius = 1.0
            self.projectionMatrix.scale(1.0/self.xRadius,1.0,1.0)
        else :
            self.xRadius = 1.0
            self.yRadius = float(Window.height)/Window.width
            self.projectionMatrix.scale(1.0,1.0/self.yRadius,1.0)        

    def addSpriteRenderContext(self,spriteRC) :
        """ Add the sprite's render context to the FBO."""
        self.fbo.add(spriteRC)

    def iterate(self,dt) :
        """ Clear the FBO every iteration. """
        self.fbo.bind()
        self.fbo.clear_buffer()
        self.fbo.release()

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        ## Initialise the post processor, which should make monochrome
        ## and draw all things that draw to its FBO.
        w = PostProcessor()

        ## initialize the sprite which should draw a rotating texture
        ## to the FBO in the post-processor.
        s = Sprite(w)

        ## update the sprite to have its vertices rotate
        def iterate(dt):
            w.iterate(dt)
            s.iterate(dt)
        Clock.schedule_interval(iterate, DT) 

        ## create a FLoatLayout that contains the post-processor
        fl = FloatLayout()
        fl.add_widget(w)

        ## Widget Setup
        if WIDGET_SETUP == 'INSIDE_SCREEN_MANAGER' :
            sm = ScreenManager()
            scr = Screen(name='Screen 1')
            sm.add_widget(scr)    
            scr.add_widget(fl)
            return sm

        else :
            return fl

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: I have just determined that this bug does not occur on my desktop which has an NVIDIA card. The bug does occur consistently on my laptop, which has Intel HD Graphics 4000 on-board graphics. I wonder if there is some way I can get more debugging information?

Comment: This occurs due to some problem with interaction with the ScreenManager's stencil. I don't know why, but it's something to look at.